# Django CBV ordering in list view not working

Tags: django, django-views

I'm not sure what is going wrong but I'm not able to order a list generated in a CBV. I followed the instruction in the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview. The model is the  following:

```
class Event(models.Model):
...
    venue = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_place.PointOfInterest',
        related_name='events',
        verbose_name=_('Event Place'),
    )
    start = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now(),
        verbose_name=_('Start date'),
    )

    def sorted_events_set(self):
        return self.event_set.order_by('start')
```

And the views.py contains:

```
class PoiDetail(SingleObjectMixin, ListView):
...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.object.events.all()
```

Everything is fine but the list in the html page is orderd by ID (reversed by the way). So I added the order_by:

```
return self.object.events.all().order_by('start')
```

But it's not working (the order remain the same). What is going on? Is this not the correct way to proceed? I also tried to add a specific ordering in the model as suggested in other questions but then I had different errors and I don't know how to write the return statement with the `sorted_events_set` method.
Thanks for helping!

**EDIT**

Here is the complete views.py

```
class PoiDetail(SingleObjectMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'app_place/poi.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(queryset=PointOfInterest.objects.all())
        return super(PoiDetail, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PoiDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['poi'] = self.object
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.object.events.all().order_by('start')
```

And this is the template:

```
{% for event in poi.events.all %}
    <a href="/e20/event/{{event.id}}" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ event.title }}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{event.description}}</p>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete view and the list in your template?

Comment: Perhaps you should replace `{% for event in poi.events.all %}` by `{% for event in page_obj %}` in template.

Comment: You need `self.object.event_set.order_by('start')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend mixing a `SingleObjectMixin` and `ListView`. They are written for two distinct goals and are incompatible in the way they achieve those. You can patch it up like you did, but if you're not very careful you can still run into a lot of unexpected behaviour, especially when relying on a call to `super`. You're actually just trying to create a detail view, so you should subclass `DetailView` with `PointOfInterest` as your model.

Now for your sorting problem: you can't pass arguments to functions in your template, so you'll have to sort the queryset in your context in the view, or create a function without any (required) arguments. I'd go with the first method, to keep logic for your view in your view code, and to prevent cluttering your model with helper methods. Either way, you'll have to keep track of which queryset you're using exactly, as sorting one queryset won't affect another queryset.

So to go with the context method:

```
class POIDetail(DetailView):
    model = PointOfInterest

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(POIDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['sorted_event_list'] = self.object.events.order_by('start')
        return context
```

And in your template, iterate using `{% for event in sorted_event_list %}`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this is not the solution I need. The first implementation follows exactly the django documentation (so I don't understand why you say that this is not recommended) and in fact I was able to retrieve all the information related to a PointOfInterest and the events related to that place (but not able to order them). With your implementation the list of events is ordered but then the information on the PointOfInterest are no more available...

Comment: [This is why](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#avoid-anything-more-complex). I didn't know the docs provide this example, but as your question shows, mixing `SingleObjectMixin` with `MultipleObjectMixin` will generally increase complexity and create unnecessary problems when you want to do more than in that example. Your template context should contain the `PointOfInterest` object as both `pointofinterest` and `object`, so it should definitely be available. You can also override `context_object_name` as a class attribute to provide your own context name.

Comment: Bingo!!! That was the missing piece... `pointofinterest` is the correct way to access `PointOfInterest`. Thanks.